# Efficient way to store an array in a RDD

Tags: java, hadoop, apache-spark, rdd, apache-flink

I need to store type arrays in a RDD. For this, I use the [ArrayWritable](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/api/org/apache/hadoop/io/ArrayWritable.html) class from Hadoop
:

```
static public class Record {
    public long id;
    public FloatArrayWritable dataArray;
}
```

It works, but I would like to be sure the objects won't be serialized if it's not needed. I would like to keep in memory as much as possible. Spark and Flink claim to keep data in memory.
Is it the case with the ArrayWritable class? Is this the efficient way to store an array?
Thanks!

**Edit :** from @mattinbits answer, for **Spark**,the efficient way is to use a **Java array** or **ArrayList** (for dynamically resizing)

Comment: Why use a Hadoop type rather than just a regular Java Array?

Comment: I'm a beginner with this framework.As I understand, if I use the Java Array, the size if

Comment: Sorry, hit enter too early... So, I'm a beginner with this framework and Java, please, correct me if I'm wrong. If I use the Java Array, the size is statically defined (the same for all records). And I would like to have a different size for each records. Also, I tried to use an ArrayList, but it's not a "POJO" type and it fails at the runtime.

Comment: There should not be any problem using an ArrayList as part of your class, can you give the specific runtime failure you get?

Comment: Thanks to have a look at my issue. A Flink test using ArrayList<Float> says : 2015-08-10 17:35:00,885 INFO  typeutils.TypeExtractor (TypeExtractor.java:analyzePojo(1305)) - Class class java.util.ArrayList is not a valid POJO type

Comment: Oh I see, this is a Flink error not a Spark one. Since you mentioned RDD, I thought you were using Spark for the records above. ArrayList should work fine on Spark.

Comment: Ok, thanks. So, I have my answer for Spark : I need to use ListArray.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Spark, a `java.util.ArrayList` should work fine. An example in Scala that I've tested:

```
import org.apache.spark.{SparkContext, SparkConf}
import java.util

case class Foo(val a: Int, val b: util.ArrayList[Int])

val conf = new SparkConf().setMaster("local").setAppName("example")
val sc = new SparkContext(conf)

val arr = new util.ArrayList[Int]()
arr.add(1)

val par = sc.parallelize[Foo](List(Foo(1, arr), Foo(2, arr), Foo(2, arr), Foo(3, arr), Foo(3, arr)))
```